# Find out which Keystore file I used

Tags: android, android-keystore

I can´t remember which Keystore file I used for my Android app. 
Is there any way to find out?
Or can I search my hard drive for all Keystore files? The problem is that the file has no extension.

Comment: This could help you -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app

Answer (score 1):

Keystore files can have any extension, so it is unlikely that searching will help you.

You can extract certain details from an already signed file, like the public key, but none of these will help you locate the corresponding file on the device.

If you did it through Eclipse, it may remember the location.

If you did it through the terminal, and it wasn't ages ago, you could keep pressing the up arrow key and hope that you reach the commands you used to sign it, which will contain the file path, or you may reach a `cd` which switches to the directory containing the file right before your run the signing commands.

If none of these work, you're out of luck and will have to search through your files manually, or create a new keystore (in which case you will have to republish your app under a new package name if it is published).

In future, please backup your keystore to multiple (secure) locations to prevent situations like this.

Comment: To add to what you've said. As per android documentation this command can extract certain details of your .apk: `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk`

Comment: This was my first Android app and I was to eager to upload it to Google Play that I didn´t read all the instructions. Big misstake!
The file is there somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

If you did it through Eclipse, try re-exporting your app using:

File>>Export>>Export Android Application

and hopefully it will still be pointing to the last location of your keystore.