# Android compare signature of current package and new release app

Tags: android

I made an application on android and published it on the play store. I signed my apk with a new private key.

Last week, i wanted to update my application with my new features. when i try to install new version on the device its give me error msg :

```
application not installed , an existing package by the same name with conflicting signature is already installed ,
```

So my question is, compare  between the key im using in my new release and the one ive in the play store , to make sure im using the same private key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, unzip the APK and extract the file /META-INF/ANDROID_.RSA (this file may also be CERT.RSA, but there should only be one .RSA file).

Then issue this command:

```
keytool -printcert -file ANDROID_.RSA
```

You will get certificate fingerprints like this:

```
     MD5:  B3:4F:BE:07:AA:78:24:DC:CA:92:36:FF:AE:8C:17:DB
     SHA1: 16:59:E7:E3:0C:AA:7A:0D:F2:0D:05:20:12:A8:85:0B:32:C5:4F:68
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
```

Then use the keytool again to print out all the aliases of your signing keystore:

```
keytool -list -keystore my-signing-key.keystore
```

You will get a list of aliases and their certificate fingerprint:

```
android_key, Jan 23, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B3:4F:BE:07:AA:78:24:DC:CA:92:36:FF:AE:8C:17:DB
```

Voila! we can now determined the apk has been signed with this keystore, and with the alias 'android_key'.

Keytool is part of Java, so make sure your PATH has Java installation dir in it.

Source:
[How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-to-find-out-which-key-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when you switch from a debug version to a release version and back.

The solution is to simply uninstall the old version.

Android Studio will detect this and offer to uninstall the old version.