# Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect - on App already on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, code-signing, keystore, android-keystore

I am trying to sign an app using the manual method found here
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Our previous external developers have sent me three keystore files that I need for this (not sure why they would require three??). When going through the process of trying to sign my app I am prompted with a **keystore password** which I do not know (I'm trying to get this from them).

Is it possible for me to change this myself? I have the three keystore files but I'm not sure if this would have an effect as the app has already been signed and released to the store and I want to **update** the app rather than release a whole new one.

I know this question has been asked before I just wasn't sure if those answers directly applied to me as my app is **already** in the Google Play store and **published**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have few suggestion for you.

1. if you don't know password of all 3 key-store then no one will help you. you must have to create new app with new package name(which is different from last live app on Google play), add new app on Google play

---

2. now in case you have password then first get last live APK. generate sign keys(sha-1 & MD5) from that APK file [check answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11331469/1168654) how to generate keys from APK.

   then after get sha-1 & MD5 from all 3 key-store and match with APK's sha-1 & MD5.  they are match then you are able to know which key-store are used for sign APK(which is currently on Google play)

   use that key-store to generate new APK :)

Comment: Looks like i'll have to do step 2 and get the passwords from the external developers as I really don't want to have the hassle of adding a whole new app in the Play Store

Comment: Do you know where in the Google Play Developer Console I can determine what key or keys it has attached to the app?

Comment: You have to fetch from last live apk file check answer how fetch from apk http://stackoverflow.com/q/11331469/1168654

Comment: thanks i understand now Dhawal you've been a big help