# Upload failed when new APK file to Android Play store Error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I already published my application in Play store, Again i want to Upload new version apk, its getting Problem.

i want to delete previous version apk or i want replace with new APK.

**Problem :** 
1.After 99% Loading its Showing error message as,

**Upload new APK to Production
Upload failed**

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

[ SHA1: 5B:68:A1:1E:89:F5:CD:B2:t1:6H:85:D1:8C:FD:01:]

and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):

[ SHA1: DB:BD:FE:53:2C:AA:JB:12:7L:BE:D6:6B:80:D6:E5: ]

Please any one help me to solve this problem.

else i want to delete previous version apk and i want replace with new APK

Comment: when you provide app update then you must `sign` your app with older `keystore`.

Comment: my old keystore is wrong , that what i changed new Keystore, can i replace new APK with previous or i want delete previous APK?

Comment: how to delete a Older Published APK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when upload app on Google play we need signed APK file. [check this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) at that time we have to use on **key store** file.

so, once upload **signed APK** on Google play with **key store**. **we must have to use that same keystore file whenever generate signed apk**, after that Google play accept new APK file.

so, your already uploaded APK file and new APK both are generated using different key store file. use same key store for new apk.

**in case you lost key store file then you are not able to upload new APK on Google play, in that case you have  to remove application from there and again upload app with different package name.**

[check my previous answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32395351/1168654)

---

**Edit:**

---

### My Old Apk Keystore was Wrong, So only solution Need to change the package name in New APK. then UnPublish the Old APK?

you must have to delete application on Google play not just apk. then add new application on google play, change package name of your app, generate new signed apk, upload on google play(this time just save key store file at safe place for future uses)

### Using that Keystore File can we generate SIgned Apk from any Other machine ?

- *yes, you can use that key store file on different machine*. just choose that key store file whenever generate new APK.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! My Old Apk Keystore was Wrong, So only solution Need to change the package name in New APK. then UnPublish the Old APK?

Comment: yes, you must have to delete application on Google play not just apk. then add new application on google play, change package name of your app, generate new signed apk, upload on google play(this time just save key store file at safe place for future uses)

Comment: Thank you friend. one more i want know ,Using that Keystore File  can we generate SIgned Apk from any Other machine ?

Comment: Thanks  for Reply Friend :)