# Retrieval lost (debug.keystore) from apk

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I know that is impossible retrieval lost keystore from apk, but this keystore is debug (auto generated).
Of course, the password is `android` and alias is `androiddebugkey`.

I finded `MD5` and `SHA1` and etc. from this page:

[How to find out which key was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-to-find-out-which-key-was-used-to-sign-an-app/11331951#11331951)

My app build by eclipse and exist in `bin` folder (not use `File > Export > Export Android Application`).

in `AndroidManifest.xml` `android:debuggable` is `false`

Can recreate debug.keystore from this data ? and signed again for new update ?

Comment: i think is not possible.

Comment: hope this may be helpful for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins/2196397#2196397

Comment: You could sort of brute force it by creating new keys and hope that one of them will have the same md5 and sha1 fingerprints. That might take a while and may not be worth the effort as it is a debug key. Why don't you just create a new one when it is for debugging only?

Comment: and also try to follow this step by step: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Google_Maps_v2_for_Android-section-36739898_GoogleMapsv2forAndroid-ObtainandAddaGoogleAPIKey

Comment: Unfortunately, I published build version (bin folder) on store. certainly eclipse use `debug.keystore` in `.android` folder for build app or not !

Comment: @HermannKlecker this will only be slow the first few hundred years, later we can use the more performant hardware available at that time. :-)