# How to add Embed Google Maps into android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps

But to do that I need Google Maps v2 API key and to get that from the Google console I have to enter SHA1 of my app.
What the problem is I can't get the SHA1 of the app because I am developing it using AIDE.

I saw a solution on Google plus blog-it suggest to use zipSigner app to get it but I can't understand it as it isn't proofed.
So how can I get the SHA1 on AIDE?

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/'

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're developing using AIDE, the APK you generate should be signed with the same key as if you were using Android Studio, this key is under ~/.android/debug.keystore. Just follow the instructions to generate your API key using this key.

If you can't find this file or AIDE works in an absolute different way (which is possible, i don't know) you can always generate an APK and get the SHA1 key from it. Just follow the instructions under this SO post: [How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

This way you can get your SHA1 key even if you don't know where's the file that signed the app.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and 
Go to your java bin directory via the cmd:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>
Now type in the below command in your cmd:
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: you are right but I am not using either Android Studio or Eclipse to develops the app but I am using AIDE.apk and I am developing the app on my android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt and type

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin (enter)
```

and type this.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_pc_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

copy value from SHA1: (05:C1:48:C8:70:DA:8D:44:27:45:3C:18:72:10:FD:9A:89:EF:00:8B) something like this