# How to find signature of apk file?

Tags: android, signature

What's the easiest way to find signature of an apk file? Please note that I'm not asking about code. I just want to find it from my pc. Signature like this one 975yYkKAQF+KST7g3ASHvHkYopq=

Answer (score 31):

```
$ $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/$BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION/apksigner verify --print-certs -v $APK_FILE
```

Example:

```
$ /Users/hborders/android/build-tools/29.0.2/apksigner verify --print-certs -v ~/Desktop/my-apk.apk

Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=Bob Smith, OU=Acme, O=Acme, L=San Francisco, ST=California, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: f1f2f3f3f21f26a67s76a6a76a76a76a76a67c78c8c78c709c90c90c09932451
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 839103847abdefcbade123713957358920
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 182831983712923f2e2e2f2a2c2fbc25
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 1024
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 8acaca8cabcaabdadc8cc99cc695ace47aec4c747c746c476cae4657c47c4765
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: b11bca4123bea24befbe5b8be9768ef078
```

`apksigner` is part of the Android SDK in the `build-tools` directory. It's the tool [`print-apk-signature`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50435738/9636) uses.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Java 7’s Key and Certificate Management Tool ( keytool) to get the signature of app. Run bellow command

```
keytool -printcert -jarfile app-release.apk
```

You can also [get Signature of a Keystore](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/how-we-can-check-sha1-or-signature-of-apk-and-keystore-file/) please check this post: [How we can check SHA1 or Signature of APK and Keystore file](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/how-we-can-check-sha1-or-signature-of-apk-and-keystore-file/)

Comment: Does not work for me, it says "Not a signed jar file"

Comment: I guess this only works for standard signed JAR files and not APKs with embedded signatures.

Answer (score 6):

```
Signature[] sigs = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
for (Signature sig : sigs)
{
    Trace.i("MyApp", "Signature hashcode : " + sig.hashCode());
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

this might help

First, unzip the APK and extract the file /META-INF/ANDROID_.RSA (this file may also be CERT.RSA, but there should only be one .RSA file).

Then issue this command:

keytool -printcert -file ANDROID_.RSA
You will get certificate fingerprints like this:

```
 MD5:  B3:4F:BE:07:AA:78:24:DC:CA:92:36:FF:AE:8C:17:DB
 SHA1: 16:59:E7:E3:0C:AA:7A:0D:F2:0D:05:20:12:A8:85:0B:32:C5:4F:68
 Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
```

Then use the keytool again to print out all the aliases of your signing keystore:

keytool -list -keystore my-signing-key.keystore
You will get a list of aliases and their certificate fingerprint:

android_key, Jan 23, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B3:4F:BE:07:AA:78:24:DC:CA:92:36:FF:AE:8C:17:DB
Voila! we can now determined the apk has been signed with this keystore, and with the alias 'android_key'.

Keytool is part of Java, so make sure your PATH has Java installation dir in it.

[How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

Comment: Please see my updated question. I'm not asking about code

Comment: why you want to find the signature itself manually or do you want to get the path of the signed apk?

Comment: No I want to find the signature itself. Not just path

Comment: But one question,/////android_key, Jan 23, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (MD5): B3:4F:BE:07:AA:78:24:DC:CA:92:36:FF:AE:8C:17:DB Voila! we can now determined the apk has been signed with this keystore, and with the alias 'android_key'.////// See my question and the format of the certificate. Why's it different? I want to get the same format like this one "975yYkKAQF+KST7g3ASHvHkYopq="

Comment: @user3548321 Did u get solution?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/warren-bank/print-apk-signature

ex: `print-apk-signature ./file.apk SHA-1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apksigner` which is available in Android build-tools to get the signature:

```
ebra@him:~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3$ ./apksigner verify --print-certs -v ~/application.apk 
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): true
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=Supreeth Herle
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: 87f10d5ab8a769bff49200039bbd5d17a0f9d0b9bcccabc36527ec3c98d978dd
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: e46872f28b350b7e1f140de535c2a835804f0be3
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: fabb11667489da8f214ed30d8efd0979
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 530468d2918764b0244a46ea406bfeb1742f4da73b6d86eefb4005c37fc04a3b
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: 884c2bf64530118dde84250ed8a03e2c2c2bb3aa
```

**And then you can convert the corresponding signature to your desired format (which is base64) using built-in Linux tools:**

```
ebra@him:~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3$ ./apksigner verify --print-certs -v ~/application.apk | grep 'certificate SHA-1' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | xxd -r -p | base64 
5Ghy8os1C34fFA3lNcKo1YBPC+M=
```

Answer (score 0):

past the full command and with apk full path it will give you all details

```
D:\Android_Sdk\build-tools\34.0.0>apksigner verify --print-certs -v C:\Users\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx_UAT_F_2.6.14_106.apk
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Verified using v3.1 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3.1): false
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=sampfe123412
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest:         96b3b7885b0b711ab6c85978f2ed12afd77a969b12c439a7698d8ac0c4e405e7
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: f40606177c1058c768cd1e92710a04e12e466ca7
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: 11299ec77a402a1200594f0f5aca09fb
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: b471e69c3404dee1d1c7996a87d500c297626f7312462dcf2bd70ed6121cbad6
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: fe40f2530abd179427fbef9efc721bea7ade9012
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: 93df4cc57d2137a215b5f6de05da0588
```