# New apk of Ionic 3 Android won't update. Gives "app not installed. The package appears to be corrupt"

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an existing Ionic application (deployed on Google play) where I have just done a new build with some bug fixes (etc). I have since updated Ionic to the latest version, and updated the Ionic CLI to 3.x etc, but other than that the build is the same (on the same machine), and I am using the **same keystore file** as before.

However, when I copy the released built apk to manually install on my Android device (as I always do before pushing to the store), and am now getting `app not installed. The package appears to be corrupt`

If I remove the existing version, then the new apk installs fine. THis is the sort of error I may expect if my signing files (keystore) has been changed, but it definitely has not, I get it from the same saved place all the time. As I have previously successfully done, I copied the key file into the platform/Android folder as described [here](https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/how-to-automatically-sign-your-android-apk-at-build-time-with-ionic). The resulting file form the build is **android-release.apk** so it has been signed.

I now have no idea how to diagnose this problem. I certainly don't want users to have to uninstall first before updating.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else could be wrong here, and how I can begin to diagnose this?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

**[UPDATE]**

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app), I examined the contents of the signing certificates using `keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA`of the previous and current builds. I have confirmed they have exactly they same contents (as I know they would)

**[UPDATE2]**

After reading some other posts suggesting it could be the `AndroidManifest.xml`, I've opened each apk using [this suggested app](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark). All the contents look **exactly** the same except for the `versionCode` and `versionName`, which are obviously set to the new version.

eg

```
file 1

versionCode='9'
versionName='1.0.0'

file 2..

versionCode='6'
versionName='1.0.1'
```

These exactly reflect the version I have for each build

Comment: The same error happened to me because I have old version signed with different .keystore of the new one in the new version. All what I did I removed the old version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally realised my problem was the version code. I am resetting the build number for each app version, and then was using the android-versionCode (in the Cordova config.xml) to store the build number. But in the Android doco it states this versionCode must always increase. As soon as I set this to 10 (in my case), the apk would upgrade.