# Locating the release keystore for an old android application on a dev machine

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore, jks

I need to locate the release signing key for an android app from 4+ years ago.  I have the codebase, and the MBP it was last worked on, but the person who worked on it was very disorganized.

I have multiple directories called /proj, /proj2, /desktop_proj, /old/proj...each has 2-3 apks in it.  Source control is a similar mess.

I don't know what IDE they used to work on this project.  I have IntelliJ, Eclipse, and Android Studio on this old machine.  I can search all of them but I don't know where to look.

I did a find and none of the keystores (.jks or .keystore) really match up.

Basically, I was thinking to go the other way -- get the current release apk from google play and check out the keystore on it.

> keytool -list -printcert -jarfile super-old-app__release.apk

Then, I can ... do something ... to find the actual name of the key used to create the signing build.  Though now that I think of it, I don't know the passwords.

Anyways, maybe I can find that, once I get the actual keys.  Does anyone possibly have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you know alias used in app, you can reverse search it for all files ( search for .JKS or .keystore or without extension ).

Write a batch program searching in complete disk with taking file name as input parameter running

```
keytool -list -keystore XXX.XXX -alias **YOURAPPAliasname**
```

Write output of above batch program to a file. All files except one should return you java.lang.Exception: Alias does not exist or incorrect format.

You can modify above batch program to additionally find signature of key to match with signed key. See solutions provided in this link - [How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

Comment: Right, but I don't know the alias that was used.  All I have is the original developer's computer and the store apk.

Comment: @warpedspeed - updated my answer. get signed key from released apk and write batch program to match it to keystore file name