# How to get the APK Cert sha256 using android studio

Tags: android

I have a requirement where i need to find the  APK Cert sha256 . I am able to find the SHA1 and MD5 using signing report in android studio. But i could not find SHA256 cert. How can i find that.

Comment: Please check this solution this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/33060008/2139332

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

```
     //HashKey Generator
public static String getProjectHashKey(Context context) {
    String hashKey = "";
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getPackageName(),
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            hashKey = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.d("KeyHash:", hashKey);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hashKey;
}
```