# Different SHA1 Key (Android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

One of my published Android apps stopped communicating with the server (I don't know why).

When I want to update it, Google Play throw an error that I have a different  SHA1 code.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your app (the update) with the same keystore used for the original app already published.

If the signing is not the same Google won't let you update for security reasons.

If you've lost your keystone I don't know how you can go from there. I guess you'll need to contact Google support from your developer account to verify your identity

Comment: I did that but google play tells me that i have different sha1 keys.

Comment: Maybe the v1 and v2 signing option at the end of the signing process? Try different combinations. Also check package name

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check the SHA1 (and other hashes) of the signing certificate used to sign your app. Answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app) list a few.

Check your signing certificate hash of your APK against what the Play Store expects. If it is the same tell that to the Play Console support, there is a bug. If the hash is different then you are not signing with the same key. You should make sure you are.