# How to print certificates of APK using apksigner

Tags: android, apk, apksigner

### How do I find the certificates used to sign my APK file?

This was discussed in SO question 7104624, `apksigner` doc on developer.android.com, and other places. They all say to use the option "--print-certs" on the `apksigner` verify command line. But I always get the error message `unsupported option: --print-certs`.

I have tried `apksigner.bat` for versions `26.0.2`, `27.0.2` and `26.0.3` all with the same result.

I'm probably doing something dumb but I can't figure out what that is. Does anybody have a similar experience?

Comment: So did you find this: [How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11331469/295004) Reminder APKs are just JARs with extra files.

Comment: Can you paste the whole command you're using?

Comment: I used: "apksigner verify MYAPP.APK --print-certs". Just now I tried "apksigner verify --print-certs MYAPP.APK" and that worked. I guess the options must come *before* the APK. My Bad. I knew it was something dumb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used `apksigner verify myapp.apk --print-certs`.
I just tried `apksigner verify --print-certs myapp.apk` and it worked. I guess the options must come *before* the APK. My Bad. I knew it was something dumb I did.