# How check is old version of apk was signed with same key as new version of apk

Tags: android, apk-signing

In my android project I has old version of my sign apk. Also I has new version of my sign apk. I need to check that old version and new version of apk was signed by same key.
How I can do this?

P.S.
Only old version was published in playstore

Comment: have you published the app in playstore??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

Comment: Only old version was published in playstore

Comment: Install old apk and try to install new apk. If sign keys are the same you can upgrade app. otherwise you cant install new apk.

Comment: I try this: "adb install -r my_app.apk", but get error:Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]