# Flutter, confirm which signing key was used during build

Tags: flutter

I'm using the command `flutter build appbundle --no-shrink --verbose` to build the app for release. However, from the log, I cannot find any information about which key was used for the signing.

I did a search for "jks", but I can't find anything about what keystore was used. Any insight on the confirmation of keystore that was used?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22983861/679553

Comment: cd into android, and run `./gradlew signingreport` which will give you what keys are associated with the project, debug and release