# This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error when I try to run my app on my android phone:

```
This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.
Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in Firebase Console
```

I have added both `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` code to Firebase console and the package name matches.

I tried every solution which is available on StackOverflow. I have spent two days to solve this problem but unfortunately, I can't.

Comment: Following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-do-i-find-out-which-keystore-was-used-to-sign-an-app) can you verify that the created APK is actually signed with the same key that you entered in the firebase console?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann
yes, i have signed with the same key as entered in the firebase console, i have entered two SHA-1 and two SHA-256 key(one from command gradlew signinReport and other from keytool command)